# Width in TD with colspan not working (Chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome

The following code doesn't render the top row correctly in Chrome (IE8 renders ok, I haven't tested in other browsers)

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
            <td width="15%">a</td>
            <td width="70%">b</td>
            <td width="15%">c
                    <table border=1>
                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top">Subtotal:</td>
                            <td valign="top">$2,464.34</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="text" style="width:500px;" />
            </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

It seems the fixed width in the INPUT control is causing the problem. If I change 500px for 80%, it magically works properly.  Or if I take out the inner table in column "c", it also works.

Why it appears the colspan=3 is being ignored?
Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/nHz7V/ I don't have the issue in Chrome, but I do in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess what! :) after dumb investigation (3 hours work) I found that for some reason display:table-cell is overwritten in chrome. so just ad table-cell display and all will be good :).

Edited answer ---------
So after checking It seems that some of the reset stylesheets puts display: block on TDs. So if it does happen you can either remove that stylesheet, edited or overwrite it.

Comment: should be a comment, although you dont have much rerputation. Try to post elaborative and explanatory answers.

Comment: Oh well... first time :) Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, good find.. that is pretty crazy. It seems to be a bug in Chrome. In this particular case, the 3rd column (c) appears to be taking on the width of the input control if it goes beyond it's `15%` of width, and takes away from the width of the middle column (b). Try increasing the `<input` tag to 700px and watch column c get wider lol.

A workaround for chrome could be to just use `%` as your units of width for that input control